# Should I CREATE TABLE every time I run COPY command

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have been tasked with moving MySQL databases to amazon redshift.  Currently I am attempting to accomplish this by

1) converting tables to CSV files

2) storing them in S3

3) creating a table in redshift

4) using the COPY command to transfer the data from S3 to redshift

I am using Python to attempt to automate this process and use boto3 to encrypt the data on the way to S3.

However, with the process I have now, I would have to manually create a table in Redshift for every csv in S3.  Since I am ultimately going to move lots of data, this is going to be very inefficient.

Is there a code I can run to detect the schema and create the table without having to go in and change the CREATE TABLE statement every time I want to load new data?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. Are you saying each time you load data the table schema is changing? Each table only gets one CSV file copied into it?

Comment: You probably cannot install extensions like [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) into the database, else you could use [`IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-importforeignschema.html).

Comment: try AWS DMS it works well for this use case

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, below answer just provide the working steps that if followed properly will do the job you're trying to automate. I did similar in my case, though the use case was not exactly as you are trying to do here.

1. Expore All the table names.
2. Loop through table names.
3. Repeat 4 to 8 for each table.
4. Export table Schema from MySQL
5. Create table in Redshift
6. Export data in TSV from MySQL
7. PUT TSV file to S3
8. Copy data into Redshift

That's all.

```
mysql -h localhost -u user -pPassword test --skip-column-names --execute="SHOW TABLES;" > database.tmp
echo "Start!"
/* Look over table name names */

for /F %%A in (database.tmp) do (
   echo "Exporting table Names for %%A"
   mysqldump -h localhost -u radhe -pPassword --no-data  database %%A > "%%A_tables.sql"
   
   psql -h redshift-hostname -d databasename -U username -f "%%A_tables.sql"
   
   mysql -h localhost -u user -pPassword  -e "select * from %%A" -B > %%A_data.tsv
   
   S3CMD put s3://yourbucket:path/%%A_data.tsv %%A_data.tsv
   
   psql -h redshift-hostname -d databasename -U username -c "copy %%A from 's3://yourbucket:path/%%A_data.tsv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';"
  
)
```

**PS**: Above for loop is for `Windows`, but you could do it change it for `Linux/Unix`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to use pandas or awswrangler to read just zero rows of data and then dump that data in Redshift (This will create the table schema **automatically** in AWS Redshift). (Copy command can't create its own table as I searched for it everywhere but in vain.) 
And, then Run the copy command.

Please find the working code below.

**Parameters**: s3_bucket,s3_prefix and destination schema + destination table

df = wr.s3.read_csv("s3://"+ s3_bucket + '/' + s3_prefix,nrows=0) 
df = df.applymap(str)
df.to_sql( destination_table, redshift_eng, schema = destination_schema ,if_exists = 'append',index = False ,method = 'multi')

s = f"""copy {destination_schema}.{destination_table}
from 's3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_prefix}'
iam_role 'Your_IAM_Role'
EMPTYASNULL
IGNOREHEADER 1
format as csv;"""

redshift_conn.execute(s)